# JFreeChart: RangeAxis in percentage stacked bar chart is in [0,1] instead of [0,100]

Tags: plot, jfreechart, percentage, stackedbarseries

In JFreeChart, I am using the `setRenderAsPercentage(true)` option for `StackedBarRenderer` .
Although the plot itself looks fine (all bars span the whole plot), the range axis labels are not showing percent values (i.e. 0 to 100) but probabilities (i.e. 0 to 1).

How can I achieve percentage values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set a `NumberFormat` for the `rangeAxis` like this:

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis("Count");
...
rangeAxis.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
...
XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, rangeAxis, renderer);
...
```

Or you can do this if you already have a plot

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis2 = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis2.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getPercentInstance());
```

You should then have an chart that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 for illustration, but see also how to [capture only the active window](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/163188).